# How to create one scrollarea in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qscrollarea

I am developing a scroll area widget with a height of 300 and adding QLabel Widgets in the scroll area, each QLabel height is 100. When adding more than 2 QLabel, the QLabel in the scroll area overlaps, and the scroll bar does not It shows that I have no way to pull the scroll bar. I want to separate the QLabel from each other. At the same time, I can pull down the scroll bar to see the remaining QLabel

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import QScrollArea, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class ScrollArea(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ScrollArea, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(500, 300)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        for i in range(4):
            lb = QLabel('hjkmlasda')
            lb.setStyleSheet("""
              border-width: 1px;
             border-style: solid;
             border-color:blue;
            """)
            lb.setFixedSize(400, 100)
            vbox.addWidget(lb)
            vbox.addStretch(1)


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        h = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        h.addWidget(ScrollArea())
        self.setLayout(h)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 500)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to set a layout in the QScrollArea but a widget, so how do I put several widgets? Well, you must use a QWidget as a container and set the widget through a layout assigned to the container, and also enable the widgetResizable property:

```py
class ScrollArea(QtGui.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ScrollArea, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(500, 300)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)

        container = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setWidget(container)
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(container)
        # vbox.setSpacing(0)
        for i in range(4):
            lb = QtGui.QLabel("hjkmlasda")
            lb.setStyleSheet(
                """
                border-width: 1px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-color:blue;
            """
            )
            lb.setFixedSize(400, 100)
            vbox.addWidget(lb)
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem very well, and thank the friend upstairs, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem very well, and thank the friend upstairs, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should set a resizable widget for the QScrollArea and place the layout on that widget. Edit the constructor as such:

```
class ScrollArea(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ScrollArea, self).__init__()

        w = QWidget()
        self.setWidget(w)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.setFixedSize(500, 300)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(w)
        . . .
```